# How could I download many NPM modules without npm install?

Tags: browser, proxy, npm

Okay, so I get it that I might be looking for a totally unexpected behavior.

My current company has nothing for me to do for a few weeks, so I would like to start a side project. The problem is, the firewall is really strong here, so I cannot download anything with Git or Npm. I also am not allowed to do any request to the IT support, since I am not in my company's office but some offices owned by a client (that applies said strict policy). In short, I am stuck with firewall and proxy policies that I cannot modify.

I may download a module's zipped archive through the browser, and install it from there. However, it has multiple dependencies, that themselves have dependencies, and so forth. And since I cannot run npm install to retrieve the dependencies, I'm stuck.

I saw multiple possible solutions in order to solve those dependencies issues:

- make NPM run all requests and downloads through the browser, since browsers are allowed to access to the network. I don't see any options for that so far.
- Download all required dependencies as tarball and step-by-step install each of them. Because of the potential number of dependencies being huge, I am looking for a huge bulk of modules commonly used to download once.

Most solutions I find make the assumption that I may use npm install properly, while my proxy doesn't allow it.

I wouldn't like to spend days on Chrome's built in game. Any idea?

Comment: make the computer use your smartphone internet connection ? so that its not using the company network and so you by-pass security policies :P

Comment: First, I don't have a local mobile provider since I don't have a flat in that new country yet.
Secondly, the computer has a setup in order to restrict any network sharing or prevent any other network source than the local company's network. I never saw such restrictions, at least our client takes security really seriously.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can create the project somewhere else, and then "import" it on your office local machine:

1. npm init
2. edit package.json with your dependecies
3. npm install
4. put everything on usb stick and put it on your local computer at work.

or

4. send an archive of the code via email and download the tarball from email at office.

Comment: `composer.json`? Perhaps you mean `package.json`?

Comment: Going through emails is currently impossible to execute due to, guess what? All webmails blocked and not allowed to synchronize my professional email address with Outlook ^^

I have to try first if an usb stick would be accepted.

Comment: Aaaaand nope. USB sticks are blocked as well. The security is strong with this one.